# How to remove rows from a csv file when compared to a list in a txt file using Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a list of 12.000 dictionary entries (the words only, without their definitions) stored in a `.txt` file.

I have a complete dictionary with 62.000 entries (the words with their definitions) stored in `.csv` file.

I need to compare the small list in the `.txt` file with the larger list in the `.csv` file and **delete the rows** containing the entries that doesn't appear on the smaller list. In other words, I want to purge this dictionary to only 12.000 entries.

The `.txt` file is ordered in separate lines like this, line by line:

**word1**

**word2**

**word3**

The `.csv` file is ordered like this:

**ID** (column 1)  **WORD** (column 2)  **MEANING** (column 3)

How do I accomplish this using Python?

Comment: I'd think of using a database like sqlite, and use executemany to the data, and write it back to csv?

Comment: You don't delete rows, you open the input file, iterate over every line, test if it matches the desired lines, write the lines you want to a temporary file and move this temporary file over the original file when you finish.

Comment: @PauloScardine, OP has to do an index search for rows which word matches the list, which is very inefficient in my opinion

Comment: @Anzel, I searching about how to use executemany.

Comment: @PauloScardine, would you have a sample code using the library csv?

Comment: @Anzel you are entitled to your opinion and it may be not the most efficient way to achieve the result he wants but does it matter? :-) Premature optimization is the root of all evil - my advice is to always go with the simplest implementation and come back with another question about how to optimize if its performance is not enough for my purposes.

Comment: @PauloScardine, you're right I just re-read OP's requirements and it seems only a workable Python answer needed. OP doesn't concern about performance/efficient at this stage. However, when I read a question like this, efficiency always becomes my first priority ;)

Comment: @Anzel BTW using sqlite for CSV transformation is very clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good answers so far. If you want to get minimalistic...

```
import csv

lookup = set(l.strip().lower() for l in open(path_to_file3))
map(csv.writer(open(path_to_file2, 'w')).writerow, 
    (row for row in csv.reader(open(path_to_file)) 
    if row[1].lower() in lookup))
```

Comment: I'm getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax in line 11

Comment: miscounted parens... fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The following will not scale well, but should work for the number of records indicated.

```
import csv

csv_in = csv.reader(open(path_to_file, 'r'))
csv_out = csv.writer(open(path_to_file2, 'w'))
use_words = open(path_to_file3, 'r').readlines()

lookup = dict([(word, None) for word in use_words])

for line in csv_in:
    if lookup.has_key(line[0]):
        csv_out.writerow(line)

csv_out.close()
```

Comment: `lookup = set(l.rstrip() for l in open(path_to_file3))` would be less memory intensive. And sets scale well.

Comment: Getting rid of the intermediate use_words is a performance improvement, to be sure but at the possible expense of showing what is going on. I wonder if sets are faster to search than hash keys, however... sounds like time for an experiment. :-)

Comment: sets are dicts without values. You save the time and memory footprint of the value object, so they scale better.

Comment: Ah... that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code, but it just wrote an empty file.

Comment: Hmm. You called csv_out.close(), yes? Any chance you're getting no matches because of extra whitespace or encoding difference? Might also try opening csv_out with 'wb' instead of just 'w'.

Answer (score 0):

One of the least known facts of current computers is that when you delete a line from a text file and save the file, most of the time the editor does this:

1. load the file into memory
2. write a temporary file with the rows you want
3. close the files and move the temp over the original

So you have to load your wordlist:

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as i:
    wordlist = set(word.strip() for word in i)  #  you said the file was small
```

Then you open the input file:

```
with open('input.csv') as i:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as o:
        output = csv.writer(o)
        for line in csv.reader(i):  # iterate over the CSV line by line
            if line[1] not in wordlist:  # test the value at column 2, the word
                output.writerow(line) 

os.rename('input.csv', 'output.csv')
```

This is untested, now go do your homework and comment here if you find any bug... :-)

Answer (score 0):

i would use pandas for this. the data set's not large, so you can do it in memory with no problem.

```
import pandas as pd

words = pd.read_csv('words.txt')
defs = pd.read_csv('defs.csv')
words.set_index(0, inplace=True)
defs.set_index('WORD', inplace=True)
new_defs = words.join(defs)
new_defs.to_csv('new_defs.csv')
```

you might need to manipulate new_defs to make it look like you want it to, but that's the gist of it.